# Dealing with outliers: Interquartile range normalization vs. Winsorization

Tags: outliers, standardization, winsorizing, interquartile

According to this [page](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_summarizingdata/bs704_summarizingdata7.html) -- "When a data set has outliers, variability is often summarized by a statistic called the interquartile range, which is the difference between the first and third quartiles."

IQR normalization is essentially standardizing by `(x - median) / IQR`, where `IQR` is 75-th percentile less 25-th percentile. Why not just winsorize the data? Let's say I perform IQR normalization as a preprocessing step before I estimate my model, the outlier is still there?

Comment: Different goals here. Using IQR when outliers are thought to be present is just a way of using a measure of variability that is resistant to them. As you appreciate subtracting the median and dividing by IQR is just a linear scaling; any outliers are still there. By the way, Winsorizing the data is far from universal practice and usually misses the main issues. Top threads here on outliers often don't even mention it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sounds like I'm an outlier as I would normally winsorize then standardize by mean/stdev. Clicking through a few outlier posts on here seem to suggest the best thing I should do is to analyze them and decide on a case-by-case basis (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/how-to-deal-with-outliers). I will be using this as part of an automated prediction process so I have to settle with a compromise.

Comment: Why do either?  Outliers are often important (unless they are data entry errors).  There are models that deal with them (e.g. several types of robust regression).